# c# Numeric Text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, key

I want to create separate textbox for numbers and string using c# code. I should not use jquery or javascript. Can anyone pls help me.

Condition:

Numeric Textbox: It should not allow characters, special characters.
String Textbox: Should not allow numbers, Special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Masked C# TextBox Control

Answer (score 0):

for numbers only

```
private void txtType1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     int isNumber = 0;
     e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out isNumber);
}
```

for text only

```
private void txtType1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int Length=textbox1.Length;
    int Loop;

    for(Loop=1;Loop<=Length;Loop++)
    {
        char c=textbox1.subString(Loop,1);

        if(( c<'a' && c>'z') || (c<'A' && c>'Z'))
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Please Enter Only Alphabets");
            e.Handle=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you would be able to paste text into the number box

Comment: yea coz..i m monitoring keydown event

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx) ; these include client-side (javascript) and server-side validation logic.